# Como removo a última "," que aparece no print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Com eu faço para remover a última `,` que aparece no `print`?

```
x = int(input())
z = range(x)

for i in z:
    n = 2**i
    print(n, end=", ")
```

Quando eu rodo o programa ele me retorna isto:

> ```
> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,
> ```

Comment: `print(*[2**i for i in z], sep=",")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver este problema devemos elaborar uma estratégia de modo que possamos imprimir uma vírgula depois de cada valor, exceto o último.

Uma das formas que podemos montar a seguinte estratégia é utilizando o seguinte código:

```
x = int(input())

for i in range(x):
    print(f'{2 ** i}, ' if i < x - 1 else f'{2 ** i}', end='')
print()
```

Observe que dentro do primeiro `print()` temos um bloco `if` que verificará se o valor de **i** é menor que **x - 1**. Caso positivo, será exibido o valor, com uma vírgula, ou seja...

```
f'{2 ** i}, '
```

...caso contrário, exibirá apenas o valor - sem a vírgula:

```
f'{2 ** i}'
```

Agora, se por acaso, desejares inserir um `ponto final` após o `último` valor, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
x = int(input())

for i in range(x):
    print(f'{2 ** i}, ' if i < x - 1 else f'{2 ** i}.', end='')
print()
```

Observe que este código é similar ao anterior, com a única exceção, na hora de exibir o último valor. Pois, na hora de exibir o último valor, também é exibido o ponto final, ou seja:

```
f'{2 ** i}.'
```

**Observação**

O último `print()` serve apenas para pular uma linha, deixando a execução do código mais legível.

Answer (score 4):

você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(z):
    n = 2**i

    if idx == len(z)-1:
        print(n)
    
    else:
        print(n, end=", ")
```

que utiliza o método **enumerate** para localizar qual é o último dígito

ou

```
for i in z:
    n = 2**i

    if z.index(i) == len(z)-1:
        print(n)
    
    else:
        print(n, end=", ")
```

o **index**

Answer (score 4):

Se você tiver uma lista de inteiro, bastaria usar método [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntá-los.

```
num_inteiros = int(input())
numeros = [str(2 ** i) for i in range(num_inteiros)]
print(", ".join(numeros))
```

Estou convertendo os números calculados para *string* pois o método [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) une um iterável de strings e não de inteiros.

---

Caso você precise fazer com `for`, é mais fácil fazer o último `print` fora do laço do que ficar testando em todas as iteração se é o último elemento do range.

```
num_inteiros = int(input())

for i in range(num_inteiros - 1):
    print(2 ** i, end=", ")

print(2 ** (num_inteiros - 1))
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-475513-6333) com o código funcionando.</sup>

Dessa maneira você precisaria validar se o número é maior que `0`, mas como você não está validando o input, estou assumindo que a entrada será sempre válida.